# Requesting a new password

Tags: services, 8

I need to request a new password via services.

I used the URL:  `<endpoint>/user/password?args['name']=test2`

but it returns `Access denied for user anonymous`

It's supposed to be used by non authenticated users so why does it return this error?.
What am I doing wrong here? What is the URL should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature was added with the resolution of this issue:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/1303400

To use this resource, make a ***POST*** to:

```
?q=rest/user/request_new_password.json
```

...and send along a name

```
name=john
```

...or e-mail address:

```
name=john@example.com
```

Comment: Hi tyler, why does it work for me but only if i remove '?q=rest' ? and it doesn't send an email it just returns [true] (no mail in the name = @)

Comment: @Mitch replace "rest" with the name of your endpoint. It returns [true] if the request was successful, i.e. it tried to send an e-mail.

Comment: yes @tyler that's right for returning 'true' but it doesn't send any mail to the e-mail address i entered as name

Comment: is it because i'm working on localhost ?

Comment: @Mitch yes localhost usually isn't configured by default to be able to send e-mails. That's something that I've never personally done, and have always migrated such code to a dev/live site for e-mail testing.

Comment: Thank you @tyler yes that's what I thought. I'll test it in server. thanks again

Comment: What I do is tell sendmail to deliver mail locally, that is, to the local mail spool. On all my sites I enable a custom module that checks the hostname and if it ends with the suffix I use for all my local domains then it adds "Bcc: myusername@myhostname" to the headers. I have my local mail spool configured in Thunderbird, so I can see the message the way it would appear if the site were live.

Comment: this solution does not work any more on drupal **8.8.3**

Answer (score 1):

According to [this sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/neeravbm/1919662) (from two years ago):

> Services module provides integration with User module but it does not provide the service to request a new password in case a user has forgotten it.

The sandbox claims to fix that.