# How do I send an email containing the user password?

Tags: services

I'm implementing a function that send the password to users who forgot it.

This is the code I developed so far.

```
function my_module_lost_password($email) {
  global $language;

  $response = array();
  $account = user_load_by_mail($email);
  $params = array(
    'subject' => "hi",
    'body' => "hello",
  );
  $from = "The_admin@gmail.com";
  $to = $email;
 drupal_mail("???", "???", $to, $language, $params, $from);
```

}

This function is called by a POST query (web service).

How do I use `drupal_mail()` to send a mail to users containing the password from the users table?

Comment: This resource is available already in the Services module: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/148826/10645

Comment: Hi tyler, yes it's available, but in my case i don't want to re-create a new password i want to send the existent password of the user who lost it by email, after loading all information by email

Comment: It's just impossible, now i understood that even if i can (it is now working) the password i send is hashed, so user cannot use it to login. so i don't have choice except storing text passwords

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you cannot send the password. You can only send a reset/one-time-login link. Passwords in Drupal are a one-way street, they can never be retrieved. To send the link is pretty easy. Use [_user_mail_notify()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7)

```
_user_mail_notify('password_reset', $account);
```

Comment: Hi Brady and thak you for your help. Yes i know i've tested the _user_mail_notify it works, but imagine i want to send a mail to a user and this mails contains his username or just a simple (useless) information such as his uid or language (any thing from the table users). how can i user the function : drupal_mail and the message is just a simple information

Comment: To accomplish that. You would gather the data you want from the user table, then use hook_mail_alter to alter the password reset mail to your desires.